# How to Solve This Type of Matrix Equation?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, tensor-products, matrix-equations, tensors

How would you go about solving the matrix equation $RSR - S = X$ for $S$?

**Some background**:

What I really want to find is a 'nice' formula for the sum

$$
S = \sum_{i=0}^n R^i A R^i
$$

where $A, R$ are matrices (and, if it helps, we know that $A = \mathbf{u}^T \mathbf{v}$ for known column vectors $\mathbf{u}, \mathbf{v}$).

The form is somewhat similar to that of a geometric series, so the best attempt at some form of a formula that I could come up with was to start by saying

$$
RSR - S = P^{n+1}AP^{n+1} - A
$$

... which leads back to the titular question...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the sum exists, you could proceed by vectorization (column-stacking) followed by matricization (column-unstacking).

First define the variables 
$$\eqalign{
 B &= R^T\otimes R &\implies B^k = (R^T)^{k}\otimes R^k \cr
 a &= {\rm vec}(A) &\implies A = {\rm Mat\,}(a) \cr
 s &= {\rm vec}(S) &\implies S = {\rm Mat\,}(s) \cr
}$$
Then vectorize the equation
$$\eqalign{
 S &= \sum_{k=0}^n R^kAR^k \cr
 s &= \sum_{k=0}^n B^ka \,\,=(I-B^{n+1})(I-B)^{-1}a{\,\,\dot =\,\,}Ma \cr
 S &= {\,\rm Mat\,}(Ma)\cr
}$$
where the geometric series was used to sum the $B$ matrices.

Comment: Just a quick question - how do you know that $(I-B)^{-1}$ is invertible?

Comment: If $(I-B)$ is singular, then ignore that formula and revert to the original sum $$M=\sum_{k=0}^n B^k$$

Comment: Cool - I thought so, but was just checking that there wasn't some reason that $(I - B)$ *had* to be invertible.